# Using to_sentence in the following for each statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following for each statement:

```
    <% @post.votes.each do |vote| %>
      <span class='voted-user'>
        <%= link_to vote.user.username, vote.user %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
```

I want to have the usernames like this:

username1, username2,  username3, and username4 using the `to_sentence` method.
But I'm not sure how to use it in this case. Any suggestions?

Comment: What I think you are trying to do:  "Bob, John, and Michael voted for this".  The problem is that you are iterating the votes, and each vote is coming from a single user.  I suspect you'll need to handle this on the models side by having each vote have many voters (through votes) and then grouping by votes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= @post.votes.map do |vote| %>
  <% content_tag :span, :class => 'voted-user' do %>
    <% link_to vote.user.username, vote.user %>
  <% end %>
<% end.to_sentence.html_safe %>
```

Although I would suggest just moving it all into a helper.

view

`<%= vote_links @post.votes %>`

votes_helper.rb

```
def vote_links(votes)
  votes.map do |vote|
    content_tag :span, :class => 'voted-user' do
      link_to vote.user.username, vote.user
    end
  end.to_sentence.html_safe
end
```

Comment: Hey almost, but sorry I think you didn't see my edit. the span tags are inside `@post.votes.map` (your solution only works when they are outside or it is impossible to do it that way?).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `map` method instead of `each` to return an array and jon them using `to_sentence`. And use [`content_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/files/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper_rb.html) for the span to tidy it up.

```
<%= 
@post.votes.map do |vote| 
  content_tag :span class: 'voted-user' do
    link_to vote.user.username, vote.user
  end
end.to_sentence 
%>
```